# Angular select using formcontrol

Tags: angular

I have a sample form which I do submit a data and edit the same by populating the same record in the Form where I developed the form using FormGroup and binding the values using form control API methods get().setvalue() for the text inputs but I am struggling in populating the DropDowns(select) in edit

I am using this line to populate the particular dropdown of the edit record as below

this.form.controls['p_county'].setValue(county[0].county_id, {onlySelf: true});

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-label">Country</label>
                <select class="form-control" formControlName="p_country">
                <option *ngFor="let element of country" [value]="element.country_id">{{element.country_name}}</option>
              </select>
                <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="f.p_country.touched && f.p_country.errors?.required">Please Select Country</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-label">State</label>
                <select formControlName="p_state" class="form-control" name="p_state">
                <option *ngFor="let element of state" [value]="element.state_id">{{element.state_name}}</option>
              </select>
                <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="f.p_state.touched && f.p_state.errors?.required">Please Select
                State</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-label">City</label>
                <select class="form-control" formControlName="p_city">
                <option *ngFor="let element of city" [value]="element.city_id">{{element.city_name}}</option>
              </select>
                <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="f.p_city.touched && f.p_city.errors?.required">Please Select City</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-label">County</label>
                <select class="form-control" formControlName="p_county">
                <option *ngFor="let element of county" [value]="element.county_id">{{element.county_name}}</option>
              </select>
                <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="f.p_county.touched && f.p_county.errors?.required">Please Select
                County</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-label">Zip Code</label>
                <input formControlName="p_zipcode" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip Code">
                <span class="text-danger" *ngIf="f.p_zipcode.touched && f.p_zipcode.errors?.required">Please enter Zip
                Code.</span>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" (click)="addCompany()">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
      </div>
```

I initialize form as below,

```
    form = new FormGroup({
    p_county: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    p_country: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    p_city: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    p_state: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    p_zipcode: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    //usr_lname:new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
  });
```

My functionality is here

```
getDDlistName(listname: string) {
    this.ddlist.getDDlist(listname).subscribe(response => {
      if (response.success) {
        this.ddlistname = response.data;
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/error']);
      }
    });
  }

  getStateDDList(code: string) {
    this.ddlist.stateDropDown(code).subscribe(response => {
      if (response.success) {
        this.state = response.data;
      }
      else {
        this.toastr.info('NO DD Data')
      }
    });
  }

  getCityDDList(code: string) {
    this.ddlist.cityDropDown(code).subscribe(res => {
      if (res.success) {
        this.city = res.data;
      } else {
        this.toastr.info('NO DD data', 'Client')
      }
    })
  }

  getCountyDDList(code: string) {
    this.ddlist.countyDropDown(code).subscribe(res => {
      if (res.success) {
        this.county = res.data;
      } else {
        this.toastr.info('NO DD data', 'Client')
      }
    })
  }

  getCountryDDList(code: string) {
    this.ddlist.countryDropDown(code).subscribe(res => {
      if (res.success) {
        this.country = res.data;
      } else {
        this.toastr.info('NO DD data', 'Client')
      }
    })
  }

  addCompany() {
    console.log('form', this.form)
    if (this.form.valid) {
      this.isSubmitted = true;
      this.gc.addCompany(JSON.stringify(this.form.value)).subscribe(response => {
        if (response.success) {
          if (this.form.controls['p_active'].value == false) {
            this.toastr.success('DeActivated Successfully', 'Client');
          }
          this.toastr.success('Saved Successfully', 'Client');
          this.router.navigate(['/default/adduser/search']);
          this.form.reset();
        }
        else {
          this.isSubmitted = false;
          this.toastr.error(response.errorMessage, 'Client');
        }
      });
    } else {
      // this.isSubmitted = false;
      this.toastr.error('Required Field information is not available. Please enter required information in highlighted fields as below.');
      this.validateAllFormFields(this.form);
    }
    return;
  }

  getCompanies() {
    this.getDDlistName("Company_Type");
    this.getStateDDList('ST');
    this.getCityDDList('CT');
    this.getCountyDDList('CY');
    this.getCountryDDList('CNT');
    let obj = localStorage.getItem('currentuser');
    this.allCompanies.p_comp_id = JSON.parse(obj).comp_id;
    this.allCompanies.p_level = 2;
    this.allCompanies.p_usr_id = JSON.parse(obj).usr_id;
    this.gc.getCompanies(this.allCompanies).subscribe(response => {
      if (response.success) {
        let data = response.data.filter(value1 => {
          if (parseInt(value1.comp_id) == parseInt(this.url[4])) {
            return value1;
          }
        });
        let type = this.ddlistname.filter(response => {
          if (response.dd_det_id == data[0].comp_type) {
            return response;
          }
        });

        let city = this.city.filter(value => {
          if (value.city_name == data[0].city_name) {
            return value;
          }
        })
        let county = this.county.filter(value => {
          if (value.county_name == data[0].county_name) {
            return value;
          }
        });

        let country = this.country.filter(value => {
          if (value.country_name == data[0].country_name) {
            return value;
          }
        });

        let state = this.state.filter(value => {
          if (value.state_name == data[0].state_name) {
            return value;
          }
        });
        this.form.get('p_zipcode').setValue(data[0].comp_zip);
        this.form.get('p_comp_address').setValue(data[0].comp_address);
        this.form.get('p_comp_address1').setValue(data[0].comp_address1);
        this.form.get('p_admin_pswd').setValue(data[0].usr_pswd);
        this.form.get('p_active').setValue(data[0].active);
        this.form.controls['p_state'].setValue(state[0].state_id, { onlySelf: true });
        //this.form.value.p_state = state[0].state_id;
        this.form.controls['p_comp_type'].setValue(type[0].dd_det_id, { onlySelf: true });
        //this.form.value.p_comp_type = type[0].dd_det_id;
        this.form.controls['p_city'].setValue(city[0].city_id, { onlySelf: true });
        //this.form.value.p_city = city[0].city_id;
        this.form.controls['p_country'].setValue(country[0].country_id, { onlySelf: true });
        //this.form.value.p_country = country[0].country_id;
        this.form.controls['p_county'].setValue(county[0].county_id, { onlySelf: true });
        //this.form.value.p_county = county[0].county_id;
        this.form.get('p_usr_id').setValue(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentuser')).usr_id);
      } else {
        this.toastr.error('Something went Wrong Pls Check System Admin', 'Client');
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Are you using reactive form or template driven form?

Comment: Reactive form @RBC9662

Comment: I think you are on right way but getting an issue to set the value in template. So plese just check once again with template and set the value of select tag like [value].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues from what I can see.

1. You name your form `form` in your **.ts** file and in your html (`<form [formGroup]="form">`), but then you are referencing the form controls in your template using `f`. Unless you have a getter that you didn't share, that will cause you issues:

```html
<!-- you need to reference `form.p_county.touched` instead of `f.p_county...` (unless you have a getter named `f`) -->
<span class="text-danger" 
  *ngIf="form?.p_country.touched && form?.p_country.errors?.required">
    Please Select Country</span>
```

2. You have an async issue in your **.ts**. Your functions (`getDDlistName(), getStateDDList(), getCityDDList(), getCountyDDList(), & getCountryDDList()`) are all making asynchronous requests for their data. This means you have to *wait* for those to complete before trying to access the data they are setting.

For example, in your current code you have:

```js
getCompanies () {
  this.getDDlistName("Company_Type");
  /* ... other code */
  this.gc.getCompanies(this.allCompanies).subscribe(response => {
  if (response.success) {
  /* ... other code */

  /* `this.ddlistname` is not guaranteed to have a value */
  let type = this.ddlistname.filter(response => {
    if (response.dd_det_id == data[0].comp_type) {
      return response;
    }
  });
  /* ... other code */
}
```

You need to change those functions to return their observable so you can wait for them to complete before calling `this.gc.getCompanies`

**Change to something like this:**

```js
/* this needs to return the observable */
getDDlistName (listname: string) {
  return this.ddlist.getDDlist(listname)
    .pipe(
      /* use tap() to set `this.ddlistname` */
      tap(response => {
        if (response.success) {
          this.ddlistname = response.data;
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/error']);
        }
      })
    );
}

/* do the same for getStateDDList(), getCityDDList(), getCountyDDList(), & getCountryDDList() */

/* change this to wait for all the requests before requesting gc.getCompanies() */
getCompanies () {
    let obj = localStorage.getItem('currentuser');
    this.allCompanies.p_comp_id = JSON.parse(obj).comp_id;
    this.allCompanies.p_level = 2;
    this.allCompanies.p_usr_id = JSON.parse(obj).usr_id;

    /* these are all async, so you need to wait for them to complete */
    /* forkJoin() will only emit a value when _all_ requests have finished */
    forkJoin([
      this.getDDlistName("Company_Type"),
      this.getStateDDList('ST'),
      this.getCityDDList('CT'),
      this.getCountyDDList('CY'),
      this.getCountryDDList('CNT')
    ]).pipe(
      /* once complete, switch to your getCompanies observable */
      switchMap(arrayOfResults => {
        return this.gc.getCompanies(this.allCompanies)
      })
    ).subscribe(response => {
      /* Note: this value here is the value from your `this.gc.getCompanies(this.allCompanies)` observable */
      if (response.success) { 
        /* ... other code */
```

3. You are doing too much when trying to set your forms values to the new data. `patchValue()` is the function you want to use to update a form's value without clearing the other form values. Also, it looks like you are trying to set form values that you don't have (`p_comp_address, p_comp_address1, p_admin_pswd`). I am assuming you just didn't post those form fields in your question, but make sure you have all those form fields in your template.

Change your code to to set the values to look like this:

```js
getCompanies () {
    forkJoin([/* other code */]).pipe(
      /* once complete, switch to your getCompanies observable */
      switchMap(arrayOfResults => {
        return this.gc.getCompanies(this.allCompanies)
      })
    ).subscribe(response => {
      if (response.success) {
        /* other code */

        let state = this.state.filter(value => {
          if (value.state_name == data[0].state_name) {
            return value;
          }
        });

        /* once you have your values, use `patchValue()` to set them all at once  */
        this.form.patchValue({
          p_country: county[0].county_id,
          p_state: state[0].state_id,
          p_city: city[0].city_id,
          p_county: county[0].county_id,
        });
        /* any other code you want */
      } else {
        this.toastr.error('Something went Wrong Pls Check System Admin', 'Client');
      }
    });
  }
```

You may not need the `[compareWith]` function since you are setting your `[value]` to a string. But it couldn't hurt to keep it there.

Comment: Thanks for the response @DJ House my requirement is I have a grid which contains some record where I will edit the record by clicking on edit button in the grid, however I used get('myname').setvalue() to fill the form for text fields but when it comes to dropdown, one of my array which receives values from API and it is not binding to the value in select option, For add it is binding if I want the dropdown for the edit record it is not

Comment: You may need to post more of your code in your question and/or provide a minimum repo that reproduces the issue you are seeing (like stackblitz.com). I’m having difficulty understanding where the exact problem could be.

Comment: I am guessing the issue could be a few different things. It could be the way you are binding to the select (using `[value]` or `[ngValue]`), how you are setting your select's option values (`*ngFor`), your `[compareWith]` function, how you are programmatically setting your select's value, or a combination of those.

Comment: I am using [value] to bind the values in option and I am filtering the array using filter method in which I store the drop-down value to get the exact value of the record to be edited by the user

Comment: You will probably need to post more of your code or a minimum repo for us to get a good idea of what the issue may be.

Comment: @KathiravanRamaswamy, I updated my answer based on what you added. Let me know if you have any questions about it, but it should work for you. Cheers!

Comment: do I use filter instead of your compare function or what about the parameters you wrote in TS for comparefn in which doest pass it in HTML @DJHouse

Comment: @KathiravanRamaswamy I don't know where or how your filter function is being used. Your `<option *ngFor="let element of county"...>` is looping over your `this.county` variable and not your `let county = this.county.filter(...)` variable. The `compareWith` just helps Angular know which value to show in the select if you programmatically change it.

Comment: I may be able to give you some more insight, but you would need to post more of your code: 1) how are you initializing your form, 2) how/where are you loading your data, 3) how are you programmatically setting your `select` value 4) where is your filter function being used?

Comment: Is there any way to do subscribe without pipe after forkjoin straightaway

Comment: Are you talking about not wanting to do the `pipe(switchMap(...))`?

Comment: Not exactly, I am asking you which done after the third point

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not following your question. You want to `subscribe()` without the `.pipe()` right after the `forkJoin()`? What do you mean by "...which done after the third point"?

Comment: My need is to do call this.gc.getcompanies after forkjoin

Comment: Ahh, I see. That is what the `switchMap` does ([see docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap)). The sequence goes like this: _after_ the `forkJoin` observable completes, switchMap _switches_ the observable to `this.gc.getcompanies(...)`. So the value in your `subscribe()` is the value returned from `this.gc.getcompanies(...)`. Does that make sense? You are _switching_ observables.

Comment: Hi, @DJ House I have accepted your answer, the insights you gave helped me to learn a lot in Angular and it is working fine. Thank you for great help